# Меньше или больше mysql regexp

Tags: php, mysql, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте. Вытаскиваю записи с применением regexp. Можно ли как то выбрать все записи значение поля которого меньше или равно условию regexp. В моем случае это число.
Сразу скажу что в моем случае без regexp не обойтись. Число завернуто в кучу символьного мусора.

Сейчас так:

```
data REGEXP 'year\\\|2017\\\|'
```

Содержание ячейки в бд такое:

```
||year|2012||year_url|<a href="/year/2012/" >2012</a>||
```

Comment: примеры можно ??

Comment: data REGEXP 'year\\\|{$year}\\\|'

Comment: Арифметических сравнений в регулярках нет. наверняка и без них можно сделать (если видеть что конкретно надо сделать с примерами), но получится что то жуткое. И еще вы не указали диалект регулярок, например в регулярках perl, в самом языке можно запросто

Comment: примеры должны включать образцы текста на который регулряка должна сработать и на какие не должна. и возможно пояснение к этому. И внести это все надо в сам текст вопроса

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: А меньше на сколько `year|32||` то же подходит ? или мы все таки рассчитываем, что год четырехзначный и из 10-21 веков ?

Comment: В данных везде четырехзначный год. Мне нужно что бы из бд выбрались все записи у которых год меньше или равен тому что указан в условии.

Comment: ну выходит что то такое: https://regex101.com/r/zkKBvD/1 но придется делать генератор регулярок на клиенте, если понадобится вместо 2017 сравнивать с другими числами. А если бы вопрос звучал "как в MySQL из такой-то строки можно достать год" то и ответ был бы совсем другим, потому что это отлично решается без регулярок

Comment: в вашем случае было бы лучше видимо `1*SUBSTR(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data,'year|',-1),1,4) < 2017`

Comment: сделайте нормальный филд с датой! хотите проблем с производительностью и маты других разработчиков при чтение данного кода?)

Comment: За хранение такого ужаса в БД надо выгонять из профессии пожизненно

Comment: Это не мое творение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал так:

SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( data,  'year|', -1 ) ,  '||', 1 ) >= '$start_year' AND SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( data,  'year|', -1 ) ,  '||', 1 ) <= '$end_year'

Answer (score 1):

Mysql regexp возвращает только 1 или 0 -- совпала ли строка с шаблоном, поэтому сравнивать какие-нибудь значения с результатом regexp не имеет смысла. Но если строки в `data` отформатированы одинаково, то вы можете сравнить их фрагменты:

```
create table `foo` (
    `id` int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    `data` varchar(255) not null,
    primary key (`id`)
)
engine InnoDB;

insert into `foo` (`data`)
values
    ('||year|1985|bar|baz'),
    ('||year|2012||year_url|2012||'),
    ('bad data'),
    (''),
    ('||year|2017|...');

select *
from `foo`
where
    `data` regexp '^\\|\\|year\\|[[:digit:]]{4}'
    and strcmp(substr(`data`, 8, 4), '2012') < 1;
```

Тут я выбрал все записи, у которых `data` соответствует шаблону и фрагмент строки с годом больше или равен `2012`.

Общая идея заключается в том, что вам следует сперва распарсить строку с датой. Если вы планируете использовать эту дату в запросах приложения (а не для отладки, например, или каких-то разовых операций), то вам следует пересмотреть структуру таблицы. Даты можно извлечь и поместить их в отдельные столбцы. Тогда по ним можно будет построить индексы и выбирать данные эффективно.